# Table cell uses a lot more width then it needs

Tags: html, css, html-table, newsletter

I'm designing a newsletter template and I'm having an issue with a table that contains graphics and text in the same row. For some reason, the graphic pushes the text all the way to the right. I'd like the text to be "connected"/left aligned with the icon as the template uses up to 3 icon sets (icon + text).

https://jsfiddle.net/o1dLoxa8/

The code doesn't look pretty right now as I've been trying everything just to make it work. Anyone able to help me out?

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="salesListText">        
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="middle" class="saleslistIcon"> 
            <img src="http://dyreparken-nyhetsbrev.s3.amazonaws.com/ikon/billetterL.png" alt="" height="28" width="28" />
        </td>           
        <td align="left" valign="middle" class="saleslistIconText"> 
            Billetter       
        </td>               
    </tr>                   
    <tr>            
        <td valign="baseline" colspan="3">  
            <h2>Kaptein Sabeltann - Kun forestillingen</h2>             
            (Kan kombineres med parkbilletter og/eller overnatting)     
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td valign="baseline">  
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="salesListSpec">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="baseline" colspan="3">
                        <h4>Pakken inneholder:</h4>
                        - Billetter til forestillingen
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top" class="saleslistPrice" colspan="3">
            <h2 style="color:#E3178A;"><span>Pris fra&nbsp;</span>240,-</h2>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

.saleslistIcon{padding-right:10px;}
.saleslistIconText{color:#B4B4B4; font-size:12px; padding-right:8px;}
.salesListText{width:100%;}
.salesListSpec{padding-top:10px; line-height:170%; display:block;}
h2 span{font-size:16px; font-weight:normal; color:#444444;}
```

Comment: is this for an HTML email or a website?

Comment: Your first table row has two cells, then you are using colspan=3 in the next row, and then you got a row with just one single cell … and you are wondering how that is not displayed “properly” …?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a table that has three columns; but you're jamming the image (small) and body text (large) in the same column (0).  That will push columns 2, and 3 way to the right.

Try putting `border="1"` onto your `table` definition to see what I mean.

I'd suggest you use the outer table to create your rows and have only a single TD.  Inside each TD then embed secondary tables for complicated layout.  I'm assuming an email newsletter, so keep your CSS to a minimum or put it inline rather than a separate style section.  A lot of email providers don't play nicely with CSS.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

From the look of your fiddle, this is to be expected. You're using a table layout, meaning that all cells in the same column will have the same width and all cells in the same row will have the same height. My immediate recommendation is to ditch the table layout and use [semantic elements](http://www.codecademy.com/en/tracks/htmlcss).

If you're hellbent on using a table layout, you need to be aware of your [`colspan` and `rowspan`](http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/tables/index_famsupp_30.html) attributes on your cells and how they affect your layout.

Answer (score 0):

Put `display:inline` inside `<tr>` where you have the icon + text.

http://jsfiddle.net/zg0zrx3v/